# Twig files inside subfolder is not recognized in symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am migrating from Symfony 3.4 to 4.4 and encounter 1 issue in render twig files. My controller:

```
src/UserBundle/Controller/UserController.php
```

this files is going to render login twig like this:

```
$this->render('@App\UserBundle:Auth:login.html.twig', []));
```

the twig file is located in:

```
src/UserBundle/Resources/views/Auth/login.html.twig
```

but it not read Auth folder correctly, it give this error:

```
Unable to find template "@App/UserBundle:Auth/login.html.twig" (looked into: /Users/myname/Sites/projectFs/src/AppBundle/Resources/views).
```

I can't understand why Auth folder is not recognized? I want to keep using this structure, not move the template in its own folder, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you check/register the namespace inside the config files? See [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/namespaced_paths.html)

Comment: I you want to migrate from to 4.4 so try to change the structure of  your project also and use the best pratices too.
Don't uses bundles and put all your logic code inside App namespace and put the views inside "templates" folder

Comment: ^@hous: Best practice to not use bundles and put everything in same namespace? What is your source for this?

Comment: @DarkBee , in Symfony3 and 2 we used to uses bundles but this philosophy  was changed since symfony 4 and they recommand to use the Default Directory Structure  https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-the-default-directory-structure

Comment: @DarkBee and they said "Don't Create any Bundle to Organize your Application Logic"  you can read it here https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/best_practices.html#don-t-create-any-bundle-to-organize-your-application-logic

Comment: [`For the rest of your application code, use PHP namespaces to organize code instead of bundles.`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/best_practices.html#don-t-create-any-bundle-to-organize-your-application-logic)

Comment: @DarkBee  sorry , "same namespace" I mean use the default namespace App and then we can make others namespaces but all starts with App\. That's what I mean. But are you agree with me to not using bundles ?